# NodeJS: Debugging child process causes incomplete runs or skipped breakpoints

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 8 to debug a scenario where a parent process forks a child, and sends it a message.

To make the child process debuggable, I'm passing **--debug** or **--debug-brk** as a parameter.

WebStorm successfully picks up the child's port, however I'm unable to have debugging behave correctly.

Here's a sample code:

**Parent**:

```
var proc = require('child_process').fork('./child.js', [], {execArgv: ['--debug']});

proc.send({say: 'hello 1'});

setTimeout(function () {
    proc.send({say: 'hello 2'});
}, 3000);
```

**Child**:

```
console.log('child started');

process.on('message', function (msg) {
   console.log("child got message", msg);
});
```

1) When **running without debug mode** and **forking** without --debug and without --debug-brk, the code runs well with the following output:

```
child started
child got message { say: 'hello 1' }
child got message { say: 'hello 2' }
```

2) When **running in debug mode** and **forking with --debug-brk** the code behaves differently - the first message never arrives to the process, and the output is:

```
debugger listening on port 62008
debugger listening on port 5858
child started
child got message { say: 'hello 2' }
```

3) When **running in debug mode** and **forking with --debug** both messages arrive, however a breakpoint inside the child's message handler is only fired for the second message (hello 2). The output is :

```
debugger listening on port 62022
debugger listening on port 5858
child started
child got message { say: 'hello 1' }
child got message { say: 'hello 2' }
```

Basically, there seems to be two issues here: --debug-brk causing code to run differently, and --debug causing some breakpoints to be skipped.

What is the correct way to debug both the parent and the child, without modifying the flow and ensuring that all breakpoints are stopped on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug; logged as [WEB-12528](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12528), please vote for it

Comment: Actually that sounds like it's not a WebStorm issue but node debugging one. Anyhow it does seem like a bug, so I'm accepting the answer.

Comment: yes - as the same issue can be recreated when debugging using node-inspector; but JetBrains should probably try to invent a sort of a workaround for it